# _mm_sfence vs __faststorefence

Tags: c++, concurrency, 64-bit, intel, windows-7-x64

According to MSDN documentation, `__faststorefence` is faster than `_mm_sfence`. In my timings it's over three times slower.

Platform: Win7-64, Visual Studio 2010 with the x64 SDK.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <xmmintrin.h>
#include <intrin.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int* x = new int;
    __int64 loops = 1000000000; // 1 billion
    __int64 start, elapsed;

    start = __rdtsc();
    for (__int64 i = 0; i < loops; i++)
    {
        *x = 0;
        _mm_sfence();
    }
    elapsed = __rdtsc() - start;

    std::cout << "_mm_sfence: " << elapsed << std::endl
              << "average   : " << double(elapsed) / double(loops) << std::endl;

    start = __rdtsc();
    for(__int64 i = 0; i < loops; i++)
    {
        *x = 0;
        __faststorefence();
    }
    elapsed = __rdtsc() - start;

    std::cout << "__faststorefence: " << elapsed << std::endl
              << average          : " << double(elapsed) / double(loops) << std::end;
}
```

Results:

- _mm_sfence average: 5.7
- __faststorefence average: 18.37

__faststorefence generates `lock or DWORD PTR [rsp], ebp`, where ebp has been xor'ed to zero, and _mm_sfence generates `sfence` (unsurprisingly)

The [MSDN docs for __faststorefence](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/subscriptions/t710k390%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) explicitly states that it's faster than `_mm_sfence` so either my test is wrong or they are. Any ideas?

Comment: Which x64? In particular, AMD or Intel? Noet that you're really wondering why `sfence` is slower despite being the dedicated instruction. And that's a CPU implementation error which obviously can be fixed in newer designs.

Comment: @msalters intel. Sfence is faster. MS says it's not

Answer (score 1):

The `AMD` processors I tried with the provided benchmark showed __faststorefence as the winner.

```
Intel - _mm_sfence: 8.61, __faststorefence: 21.60
AMD 1 - _mm_sfence: 138.21, __faststorefence: 90.96
AMD 2 - _mm_sfence: 55.21, __faststorefence: 20.08
```

This was with VS 2013.
_mm_sfence = sfence
__faststorefence = lock or dword ptr [rsp],esi

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare __fasstorefence (full fence) vs _mm_sfence (store fence).

You need to compare __fasstorefence (full fence) vs _mm_mfence (m - full fence).

Comment: In the interest of answering the question, could you explain why they can't be compared? I know you already said they're different kinds of fences, but that might not mean much to the asker.